# Can’t install DotNetCore VS2015 Tools Preview2 for Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

i'm trying install Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with Update 3 on my Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter without any error. And next i'm install DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2 but is not success.

Here is full content of error

> Setup has detected that Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 may not be completely installed. Please repair Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, then install this product again.

I was repair with 3 times but nothing changes :(

And here is full log file content: (sorry my content have more than 30.000 words so that i will attach it to pastebin site)

```
http://pastebin.com/DQDUBETT
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Same issue with 2015 community. Tried repair and a full reinstall with the new full vs+sp3 .iso, Nothing changed.

Comment: add to manually copy msbuild targets for DotNet and DotNet.Web from another machine to open & build my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution at Github. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1626

Simply run the setup exe from the command line with following parameter and it should work.

```
SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```